# Integration Question - MGF

Tags: calculus, integration, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to integrate this function with respect to z.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}(1-2s)+tz}dz$$
The answer book is telling me it should be:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{1-2s}}$$

If someone has any idea how that's possible that would be awesome! Thanks.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhmMk.jpg)

Comment: Please write out the original integral using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integral is of the form:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a\phi^2}d\phi=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

And if you substitute again with $$\phi=z-\frac{t}{1-2s}$$
You'll get the integral into the required form.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to standard tables of gaussian integrals to get the answer. Typically when solving these types of problems you say "refer to the table of integrals for this gaussian integral". The identity you need can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function):
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2+bx+c}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}+c}
\end{equation}

So for your integral:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(1-2s)}{2}z^2+tz}dx
\end{equation}

you have $a=\frac{1-2s}{2}$, $b=t$ and $c=0$.

As such your solution is:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-2s}}e^{\frac{t^2}{2(1-2s)}}
\end{equation}

This has the same form as the answer you provide, however, differs by a multiplicative factor. Either the book is missing this factor or there could be a mistake earlier in your math.

Comment: If you needed to prove the guassian integral you can refer to the proof with polar coordinates [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html)

Comment: I think that you have one extra term : if I am not mistaken, the result could be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 s}}e^{\frac{t^2}{2 (1-2 s)}}$ provided $\Re(s)<\frac 12$

Comment: Yes the $2\pi$, the answer will be corrected. It is still odd that this result doesn't match what was provided in the question.

Comment: I am almost 80. Have you an idea of the number of errors, typo's or mistakes I saw in textbooks ? Cheers ;-)